# What is the best way to test RailsApps App in Gitlab CI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, railsapps, gitlab-ci

I've created Ruby on Rails app using [Rails Composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/) and I want to use it with Gitlab CI (v5.0.1 on OS X 10.9.4) with Gitlab CI Runner also on OS X 10.9.4.

What I should use as build steps? I started with:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
rvm use ruby-2.1.2@myapp
bundle install
rspec spec
```

I used `.bash_profile` because `rvm` doesn't work without it. Is there better way?

I found that some files are not in Git (like `database.yml` and `application.yml`). What is the best way to add them back or how to setup them in Gitlab CI?

EDIT:

I've added back default `database.yml` as `database.example.yml`. Now, I use these build steps:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
cp config/application.example.yml config/application.yml
cp config/database.example.yml config/database.yml
rvm use ruby-2.1.2@myapp
bundle install
rspec spec
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to end them with "thanks".